# Ceiling fixture. How to go wireless? Electrician?

Tags: lighting, switch, light-fixture, ceiling

The light switch for the kitchen ceiling fixture is located between the refrigerator and the dining room wall (made of plaster). That space is not wide enough for me to reach the switch.

I think wireless may be the solution but am not sure how to install it.  Do I need an electrician?

Comment: Whether you need an electrician isn't up to us. This question is off topic as both vague and opinion-based.

Answer (score 5):

That does not work, it's a Code violation.

You may notice how you can go into a room you've never been in, and usually find the light switch by groping around. (notably: small restaurant bathrooms). That doesn't happen by accident; it's a Code requirement to put switches in those locations.

Every habitable room must have a light switch that works.  *That's not for you; that's for guests, particularly the kinds wearing uniforms (First Responders)*.

So any method where you "control it from your phone" or other "exclusive to you" control method is right out.   What you can do is:

- Change the light to one that is motion-sensor activated, and simply leave the switch on (optional: hardwire it on).
- Get a narrower refrigerator so you have the hand space to reach the switch. (I have that situation myself; the home's wiring *pre-dates* houses having refrigerators).
- Use a smart switch or smart-bulb that has a matching, "wireless, battery remote switch" - looks like a real switch but doesn't have any wires.  Mount this in a legal location.
- Hire an electrician to relocate the switch (or if the homeowner-occupant, gain the competence to DIY this task).  A pro should insist on a legal location. A big advantage of pros is some of them *have supernatural skill* with the flexible drill bits and fishing tapes, and can often route wires without disturbing plaster and paint.

Comment: +1 for fishing supermen.   Just make sure you get one of those.  The really good ones unfortunately gravitate to low voltage work, leaving behind the other species of electrician, the  "drywall is cheaper than my time" sort.  :(

Comment: Does code allow a required switch to be just outside the room?  If so, turning the switch around to the wall directly behind it might be the simplest solution (unless that location is outdoors or also blocked by furniture).

Comment: @jay613 I have strong feelings about that question, as I'm rather fond of switches on the outside of bathrooms.  However unfortunately the letter of Code does not say that.  An inspector might go "that's fine" though; it's their final say.

Answer (score 3):

As far as whether you need an electrician or not, that depends on your skills (and willingness to learn new skills) and local rules (which vary considerably).

There are three basic solutions:

- Wireless

Replace the existing switch with a *smart* switch that includes wireless capability, and add a wireless remote (often looks just like another switch, but battery powered) which can be placed anywhere. The catch is that the smart switch will *usually* require neutral, and neutral may or may not be in the existing switch box. If it is, this is the easiest solution, and least likely to need an electrician. If it is not, then this is a comparable solution to the others in terms of work involved.

- Add a 3-Way Switch

Replace the existing switch with a 3-way switch. Run a 3-wire (plus ground) cable from the existing switch location to a more convenient location. Install a 3-way switch at the new location. This will require at least some work inside the wall to run the cable.

- Move the Switch

Run a 2-wire (plus ground) or 3-wire (plus ground) cable to a more convenient location. 2-wire vs. 3-wire will depend on what is in the box, because you should provide neutral at the new location if neutral is available. Move the switch to the new location. Put a blank cover plate on the old box. This will require at least some work inside the wall to run the cable.